# Cellular chain complex of a CW-subcomplex $X'\subseteq X$

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology, homological-algebra, cw-complexes

Let $X$ be a (possibly infinite) CW-complex, with a CW-subcomplex $X'$. The cellular chain complex of $X$, with coefficients in an abelian group $A$, is given by $\tilde{C}_n(X;A)=H_n(X_n,X_{n-1};A)$. I know that one can prove that the map $H_n(X, X';A)\to H_n(X/X',X'/X';A)$ is an iso, by showing that $(X,X')$ is a "good pair". However, I was wondering if there exists a more sophisticated proof using cellular homology, using the isomorphism $H_n(\tilde{C}(X,A))\to H_n(X;A)$. My idea was to find a chain complex $D_\bullet$ such that $0\to \tilde{C}_\bullet(X')\to \tilde{C}_{\bullet}(X)\to D_\bullet\to 0$ is a short exact sequence of chain complexes, then take homology to obtain a LES $$\cdots\to H_n(X',A)\to H_n(X, A)\to H_n(D_\bullet)\to H_{n-1}(X; ,A)\to \cdots$$ and compare this LES to the LES for the pair of spaces $(X, X'):$
$$
\cdots\to H_n(X',A)\to H_n(X,A)\to H_n(X, X',A)\to H_{n-1}(X',A)\to \cdots,
$$to relate $H_n(X, X',A)$ and $H_n(D_\bullet)$. My only problem is how to choose $D_\bullet$. For the singular chain complex, the inclusion $X'\subseteq X$ allows for taking the quotient $C_n(X.A)/C_n(X',A)$, but can we do the same for the cellular chain complex, and why? I don't see a priori why $H_n(X_n',X_{n-1}';A)$ can be seen as a subspace of $H_n(X_n,X_{n-1};A)$. Moreover, if I set $$
D_n=\tilde C_n(X)/\tilde C_n(X')
$$ how do I relate $H_n(D_\bullet)$ to the relative homology $H_n(X/X',X'/X';A)$?

EDIT THANKS TO TYRONE: I reduced it to the case that I have to show that $$H^{CW}_n(\tilde{C}_n(X)/\tilde{C}_n(X'))\cong \tilde{H}_n(X/X')$$ But I am an unaware how I have to deal with the cellular homology of the quotient of two cellular complexes. My gut feeling tells me that the quotient complex $\textbf{should}$ be isomorphic to $\tilde{C}_\bullet(X/X')$, which has a natural CW-structure, but I am unable to prove this iso.

Comment: I'm sure this will be circular as all the good properties that cellular homology has relies on the fact that relative homology is homology of the quotient.

Comment: Isn't this immediate? If $X'$ is a subcomplex of $X$, then the cellular chain complex $C_*(X')$ is a subcomplex of $C_*(X)$ and there is no difficulty in forming $C_*(X)/C_*(X')$.

Comment: Why is the cellular chain complex a sub complex in this case? The cellular chain complex is a relative homology group, why is the 1 a subgroup of the other?

Comment: This SES will give rise to a LES, but what is the homology of the quotient $C_*(X)/C_*(X')$?

Comment: Sorry, you didn't tag me so I didn't notice your question. The cellular chain group $C_n(X')$ is the free abelian group generated by the n-cells of $X'$. If each n-cell of $X'$ is an n-cell of $X$, then $C_n(X')$ is a subgroup of $C_n(X)$. See, for instance, Proposition 2.3.1 in R. Geoghegan's *Topological Methods in Group Theory*.

Comment: The short exact sequence of chain complexes $0\rightarrow C_*(X')\rightarrow C_*(X)\rightarrow C_*(X)/C_*(X')\rightarrow 0$ gives rise to a long exact sequence in homology which gives you $\widetilde H_*(X/X')\cong H_*(C_*(X)/C_*(X'))$.

Comment: @Tyrone I do get that iso you describe by the LES, but I dont see how you can get from $H_*^{CW}(X,X')$ to $H_n(X,X')$. I know that the singular homology and the cellular homology are isomorphic, but do we have a similar result for the relative homology and the relative cellular homology?

Comment: I want to use the five lemma between the LES that arises from the pair of spaces $(X,X')$ to the LES that arises from the discussion you described, but how do I get a map $H_n^{CW}(X,X')\to H_n (X,X')$?